# how to update a map value by reflection in Golang

Tags: go, reflection

I encountered a problem, I expect to make a general method to update the value in the map, as in the below example：

What I mainly want to do, provide a general method

1. Read the configuration;
2. Verify that the configuration is valid
3. Deserialize the configuration to the specified object

```golang
type ConfigKey string

var StudentKey ConfigKey
var TeacherKey ConfigKey

type Teacher struct {
    Age int `json:"age"`
}

func TestReflect(t *testing.T) {
    // update student
    student := make(map[int]Student)
    update(StudentKey, &student, func(value interface{}) bool {
        if m, ok := value.(map[int]Student); ok && m[0].Name == "test" {
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
    fmt.Println("outer:", student)
    // update teacher
    teacher := make(map[int]Teacher)
    update(TeacherKey, &teacher, func(value interface{}) bool {
        if m, ok := value.(map[int]Teacher); ok && m[0].Age == 1 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
    fmt.Println("outer:", teacher)
}

// func to auto update config, For make a general method
func update(key ConfigKey, ori interface{}, validate func(value interface{}) bool) {
    valueStr := getConfigValue(key)
    temp := copyInterface(ori)
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(valueStr), &temp)
    if !validate(valueStr) {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("inner:", temp)
    ori = temp
}

func getConfigValue(key ConfigKey) string {
    switch key {
    case StudentKey:
        return `{"0":{"name":"test"}}`
    case TeacherKey:
        return `{"0":{"age":1}}`
    }
    return ""
}

func copyInterface(a interface{}) interface{} {
    return reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(a).Elem())
}
```

The expected output result is:

```
inner: map[0:map[name:test]]
outer: map[0:map[name:test]]
inner: map[0:map[age:1]]
outer: map[0:map[age:1]]
```

But the actual output is:

```
outer: map[]
outer: map[]
```

How can I achieve the expected output?

Comment: You can link to other things things for reference, but your question should be self contained (the link should not be required to understand the question). Also, asking a question without presenting your own attemps is a good way to get downvoted and no answers.

Comment: debug your code. For example : add `fmt.Print...` instructions within your validate function. You can print the type of any variable using `"%T"` : `fmt.Printf("type of x: %T\n", x)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected update function with commentary describing how the function works.

```
func update(key ConfigKey, ptarget interface{}, validate func(interface{}) bool) {
    valueStr := getConfigValue(key)

    // Get target value. Target is expected to be a pointer to
    // a value. Elem() dereferences the pointer.
    target := reflect.ValueOf(ptarget).Elem()

    // Create a new empty value. New returns a pointer. Elem()
    // dereferences the pointer.
    scratch := reflect.New(target.Type()).Elem()

    // Unmarshal to the scratch value.
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(valueStr), scratch.Addr().Interface())
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Call the validation function.
    if !validate(scratch.Interface()) {
        return
    }

    // Assign the scratch value to the target value.
    target.Set(scratch)
}
```

[Run the test on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_x1Nf4jLTVB)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working.It seems that I still know too little about reflection.